# Pass a Simple URL Variable into and Input Field via Javascript

Tags: javascript, url, variables

I have found plenty of ways to do this via PHP but on a simple HTML site I have run into a roadblock. And I'm not really strong on JS so that doesn't help.

Basically I am passing a very simple URL variable (a ref #) via a link (...com/Apply-Online?12345) and I need to load it into an input text field on a form in the linked page. Most of the scripts I have found want to parse out multiple variables and it gets really complicated in a hurry. Since I only have 1 value it seems like there should be an easy way to parse the variable from the URL and pass it into a var and pass that to the ID of the field.

I have the window.onload part figured out. I just need the code to parse out the variable.

```
window.onload = function(){
    document.getElementById("input_id").value = 12345;
};
```

Answer (score 2):

It is as simple as:

`document.getElementById("input_id").value = location.search.replace('?','');`

Comment: I knew it would be something simple! Works perfectly Martin. Thanks so much.

Comment: Anytime, feel free to accept the answer if it was what you need ;)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your link includes a variable name, such as `...com/Apply-Online?var1=12345`:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function $_GET(q,s) { 
        s = s ? s : window.location.search; 
        var re = new RegExp('&'+q+'(?:=([^&]*))?(?=&|$)','i'); 
        return (s=s.replace(/^?/,'&').match(re)) ? (typeof s[1] == 'undefined' ? '' : decodeURIComponent(s[1])) : undefined; 
    }

    window.onload = function(){
        document.getElementById("input_id").value = $_GET('var1');
    };
</script>
```

Source: http://www.onlineaspect.com/2009/06/10/reading-get-variables-with-javascript/

Answer (score 0):

```
var value = document.location.search;
```